# Como separo números de un vector en Java

Tags: java, array

mi duda es: Si es posible separar dígitos o números de un vector y luego de separar ciertos números como los puedo juntar para que sea un solo numero?

Un Ejemplo:

### **Vec[0]=1 vec[1]=0 vec[2]=0** vec[3]=0 vec[4]=1 vec[5]=1

Solo quiero obtener del vec[0] al vec[2].
en ese caso solo quiero obtener el valor de cada uno que sería: 1, 0, 0,
y como es que se puede agrupar de tal forma que de un solo numero en este caso que de el numero: 100

Gracias, espero me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 1):

El siguiente código extrae los 3 primeros digitos y arma el numéro sumando:

`1 * 100 + 0 * 10 + 0 = 100`

```
int vec[] = {1,0,0,0,1,1};
int valor = 0;
for(int i=0; i < 3; i++){
  valor = valor * 10 + vec[i]; 
}
System.out.println(""+valor);
```

Answer (score 1):

!Buenas!

Si lo que quieres es agrupar los números del vector para que se muestren seguidos. Esta es otra opción:

```
    int test[] = {1,0,0,0,1,1};

    for(int i=0; i < 3; i++){

        System.out.print(test[i]);
    }
```

En el `for` le dices **hasta que** numero del array quieres avanzar, y lo vas mostrando con un `print` y no usando un `println` ya que **los mostraría uno debajo de otro**.

Y si en futuros casos, quisieras que se muestren separados, o de alguna otra forma... Solo tienes que "jugar" con el `System.out.print`.